# Angular JS <a href> route back to LogIn

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, mean-stack, ngroute

I've placed a below link in my code

```
<a href="/#/list/' + data._id + '" class="btn btnprimary1" > LIST </a>
```

It should routed to below point

```
 .state('index.list', {
            url: '/list/:id',
            templateUrl: '/list.html',
            data: { pageTitle: 'listing', pageFilter: 'off' },
            controller: 'listController',
            });
```

Instead of that it routed to the main page /# and from that it checks login and rerouted to my current page

Is it a correct way to place href in angular code to route to a state with specific Id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`ngHref`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref):

```
<a ng-href="/#/list/{{data._id}}"></a>
```

Or preferable [`ui-sref`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref):

```
<a ui-sref="index.list({id: data._id})"></a>
```

Comment: @AbhishekParikh Your value of the href attribute is not an expression angular will parse and compile. It's missing the double {{ .. }}.(And it's not even a valid js expression, look at the quotes!). ng-href and ui-sref are different, because these are directives.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the fallowing approach

```
<a ng-href="/#/list/{{data._id}}">LIST</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use ng-href directive in place of href tag in Angular.

```
<a ng-href="http://127.0.0.1/projectFolder/#/list/{{data._id}}" class="btn btnprimary1"> LIST </a>
```